# Python Reading CSV files column by column

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to manipulate a csv file of data with a python program.

the csv file looks like this with different length rows:

```
1,B,T,P,B,B,B,P,P,P,T,P,P,P,P,T,B,P,P,B,P,P,B,B,P,P
2,T,P,B,P,B,B,P,P,B,B,T,P,B,B,T,P,P,B,B,B,B,P,T,B,T,B,B,B,P
3,P,P,B,B,P,B,T,T,B,P,P,B,B,B,P,B,B,P,P,B,P,T,P,B,P,P,P
4,B,B,P,P,P,B,P,B,T,B,P,P,B,B,P,P,B,B,B,T,B,P,B,B,B,P,P,B
```

So in Row 1 I want to evaluate:

> B vs T

then

> T vs P

then

> P vs B

until the end

> B vs P

Then start on the next row, until the end of file.

I am using:

```
readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')

for row in readCSV:
    for col in row:
```

I have tried `row[1]` vs `row[2]` but not sure how to increment these for different length rows.

Looking for suggestions for the easiest way to evaluate these so that I complete every row?  Basically I am just testing if new column [2] is equal to the previous column [1], for the entire row.

Comment: Please edit the question to include your expected output for this data.

Comment: What does "B vs P" mean?

Answer (score 0):

The lines have different length, so I would not use the csv reader. I suggest to read the file line by line, splitting the lines at the commas, and compare each position individually:

```
import itertools

with open("data.csv", "r") as datafile:

    line1 = datafile.readline()

    for line2 in datafile:

        tokens1 = line1.strip().split(',')
        tokens2 = line2.strip().split(',')

        print(" --- Comparing lines %s <=> %s --- " % (tokens1[0], tokens2[0]))

        for (a, b) in itertools.zip_longest(tokens1[1:], tokens2[1:]):
            print("%s <=> %s : %s" % (a, b, "Equal" if a==b else "Not equal"))

        line1 = line2
```

The output with python 3.4 is:

```
 --- Comparing lines 1 <=> 2 ---
B <=> T : Not equal
T <=> P : Not equal
P <=> B : Not equal
B <=> P : Not equal
B <=> B : Equal
B <=> B : Equal
P <=> P : Equal
P <=> P : Equal
P <=> B : Not equal
T <=> B : Not equal
P <=> T : Not equal
P <=> P : Equal
P <=> B : Not equal
P <=> B : Not equal
T <=> T : Equal
B <=> P : Not equal
P <=> P : Equal
P <=> B : Not equal
B <=> B : Equal
P <=> B : Not equal
P <=> B : Not equal
B <=> P : Not equal
B <=> T : Not equal
P <=> B : Not equal
P <=> T : Not equal
None <=> B : Not equal
None <=> B : Not equal
None <=> B : Not equal
None <=> P : Not equal
 --- Comparing lines 2 <=> 3 ---
T <=> P : Not equal
P <=> P : Equal
B <=> B : Equal
P <=> B : Not equal
B <=> P : Not equal
B <=> B : Equal
P <=> T : Not equal
P <=> T : Not equal
B <=> B : Equal
B <=> P : Not equal
...
```